# any scripts to create access control in gerrit using DSL format

Tags: git, dsl, puppet, gerrit

In gerrit, we need to setup the [access control for projects](http://gerrit-documentation.googlecode.com/svn/Documentation/2.4/access-control.html), it is done via web page mostly, which is efficiency to initial it.

In internet, there is solution to manipulate the database (like gsql for h2) in scripts, but it is low level and inefficiency as well.

I wonder whether

1. there is better API currently we can use to create access control in gerrit in easy way
2. or any people already write the configuration in DSL format, that scripts can deal with gerrit (sql over ssh).
3. or any puppet good module for this ?

My expected configuration in DSL looks like below

```
Group1; Read on refs/heads/* and refs/tags/*
Group2; Push to refs/for/refs/heads/* and refs/changes/*
Group3; Push merge commit to refs/for/refs/heads/* and refs/changes/*
Group4; Forge Author Identity
Group5; Label: Code review with range -2 to +2
Group6; Label: Verify with range -1 to +1
Group7; Submit
```

And script helps for the rest

Comment: Sounds like a missing feature. JIRA time :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

```
git fetch origin refs/meta/config
git checkout -b config FETCH_HEAD
```

Update your `project.config`:

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/meta/config
```

Answer (score 1):

You can download the refs/meta/config branch and change the project.config file.
like this

```
git fetch origin +refs/meta/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
git checkout -b config --track origin/config
```

The you just open the `project.config` file and make the access changes you need, the you push it to gerrit

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/meta/config
```

You have to have read access to refs/meta/config to be able to this. 
Those access has be granted from the gui.

To bypass this when creating new projects you can add this into all-projects that project_creators have read and push access to refs/meta/config.

Cheers

Comment: any link for this information, i got invalid refspec. Which version of gerrit is supported for this ?

Comment: command has errors, can you fix it before I select as answered

Comment: Sorry holiday season :) i updated the commands, perhaps the errors you get are related to the access rights in gerrit,